# Is it normal for AWS Lambda functions to take nine hours to start?

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda

We're using some asynchronous Lambda functions to process images and store them to S3. In all my testing before we deployed to production the functions were run as soon as we invoked them. However, over the weekend we had a batch where there was a gap of several hours between us invoking the function and it actually running.

For example, our logs showed we invoked a function at 2015-12-13 02:46:10 (UTC), but Lambda's logs show it didn't run until 2015-12-13T12:09:33.909Z. I don't think we were being throttled as not a single Lambda function ran between 2am and 9:46am UTC.

We moved to Lambda to speed up our image processing. Is this normal? Is this just a delay we're going to have to live with?

Comment: No that's absolutely not normal. You might want to reach out to AWS support and see what the issue was.

Comment: Are you sure you didn't have network problems, or internal problems in your script before the command hit AWS? As reference, my Lambda function is usually woken up in roughly 2-3 seconds after a cold start.

Comment: @thoean That's been our experience most of the time too. We've got a monitoring service set up and our service was definitely taking inbound connections in all that time. Very mysterious.